# HttpInterceptor - unwrapping API response

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

How to unwrap API response using HttpInterceptor?

My API response model:

```js
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
   data: T;
   statusCode: number;
   errorMessage: string;
}
```

What I would like to achieve, to last interceptor in my interceptor chain returning only `data` property from above model.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UnwrapInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.url.match('/api/')) {
          console.log('Unwrapping data: ', event.body.data);
          return of(event.body.data);
        }
        return event;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I've got console log from interceptor when requesting data, but data somewhere disappears and finally I got nothing in response.

My test component that calling API after button click:

```js
@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-user-list-page',
  templateUrl: './user-list-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list-page.component.scss']
})
export class UserListPageComponent implements OnInit {
  userList: User[];

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  performRequest() {
    this.http.get<User[]>('/api/users').subscribe((data: User[]) => {    
      console.log('Received from component: ', data); <==+ never executed 
      return (this.userList = data);
    });
  }
}
```

`HttpService` in above component is just calling Angular `HttpClient`.

I am using Angular `7.1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just returning an observable of the body data, you should still return a `HttpResponse` instance that just contains a mutated body, e.g. by cloning the response:

```
if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.url.match('/api/')) {
  console.log('Unwrapping data: ', event.body.data);
  event = event.clone({ body: event.body.data });
}
return event;
```